# JSON arrives weird when it reaches Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

That is sent from a mobile application to my rails application:

```
{"k":true,"size":[3,3,1],"data":[[[0],[1],[2]],[[1],[2],[3]],[[2],[3],[4]]]}
```

But for some reason I'm getting the request params like this:

```
{"{\"k\":true,\"size\":"=>
{"3,3,1"=>
{",\"data\":"=>
  {"0"=>
    {","=>
      {"1"=>
        {","=>
          {"2"=>
            {","=>
              {"1"=>
                {","=>
                  {"2"=>
                    {","=>
                      {"3"=>
                        {","=>
                          {"2"=>
                            {","=>
                              {"3"=>
                                {","=>{"4"=>{"}"=>nil}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}},
"action"=>"create",
"controller"=>"maps"}
```

I need to save it in my database, but I honestly do not know why that json is deformed in this way or how I can treat it for what I need.

Comment: Can you capture what's going over the wire with fiddler or a similar tool?

Comment: I just realized that i'm receiving the json like this because is getting taken as the params name. The problem is in the mobile app.. Thanks for taking the time to answer @akatakritos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that i'm receiving the json like this because is getting taken as the params name. The problem is in the mobile app.

They are sending something like:

```
"{"k":true,"size":[3,3,1],"data":[[[0],[1],[2]],[[1],[2],[3]],[[2],[3],[4]]]}" => ""
```

instead of:

```
"data" => {"k":true,"size":[3,3,1],"data":[[[0],[1],[2]],[[1],[2],[3]],[[2],[3],[4]]]}
```